# WordPress Website Browser Compatibility issue with IE

Tags: theme-development, browser-compatibility

I noticed our website is not rendering correctly in old IE 10 and under. After looking into the console there seems to be some DOM conflicts. Is there something I need to update in my CSS to render for old IE?

https://americanmotorcyclist.com/

Comment: If by DOM conflicts you mean JavaScript errors, CSS won't help. I would suggest checking your site's analytics to see whether you have many visitors using old versions of IE. If so, you can troubleshoot further - but if less than 5% of your visitors use those old versions, it might not be worth your time fixing for the small percentage that are using such an outdated browser. You might instead want to offer users an Old-IE-only message recommending they upgrade for security and user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has stopped support for IE 10 and so should you.
If your company needs IE 10 then you should advise your users that using IE 10 is no longer secure and can pose a serious security threat just by using it.

IE 10 will also not be able to render a large majority of websites and not just your website. So don't feel too bad about IE 10.